# Prove $(\exists x)A\to((\exists x)(A\wedge(B\vee C))\equiv B \vee (\exists x)(A\wedge C))$, if $x$ is not free in $B$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Prove $(\exists x)A\to\big((\exists x)(A\wedge(B\vee C))\equiv B \vee (\exists x)(A\wedge C)\big)$, if $x$ is not free in $B$.

I've tried multiple different ways and I'm not able to see a good path forward. I feel like my best bet is to start from:

$$A[x:=z]\vdash\big((\exists x)(A\wedge (B\vee C))\equiv B\vee (\exists x)(A\wedge C)\big)[x:=z]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Long comment* : it works.

The trick is to prove that $A \vdash A \land (B \lor C) \equiv B \lor (A \land C)$.

So, using **Coroll.6.1.11** :

> $A[x := z] \vdash (\exists x) (A \land (B \lor C)) \equiv (\exists x)(B \lor (A \land C))$, with $z$ fresh.

Now we can distribute $\exists x$ over $\lor$ in the RHS, and - taking into account the fact that if $x$ is not free in $B$, then $\exists x B \equiv B$ [**Ex.11**, page 188] - we get :

> $A[x := z] \vdash (\exists x) (A \land (B \lor C)) \equiv B \lor (\exists x)(A \land C)$.

Now, using **Coroll. 6.5.8** we get :

> > $(\exists x)A \vdash (\exists x) (A \land (B \lor C)) \equiv B \lor (\exists x)(A \land C)$.